# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on accessing UIImage's size property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

The `image` is an instance of `UIImage`. The first line executes with no problems, but the second one gives an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at runtime.

```
NSLog(@"SCALE: %f", image.scale);
NSLog(@"TEST: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
```

I can view the values of `size` property in Xcode by mouse-hovering it though.

[image]

Can you please help me in understanding what's wrong with it and/or what I might be missing?

Tested on a device and in simulator running iOS 8.

UPD: This is how I'm creating the image:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGFloat scale  = 1.0f;

CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullResolutionImage];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)rep.orientation];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I just tried to delete the last line `CGImageRelease(imageRef);` and it seem to be fixed the problem. But I do need to release the `CGImageRef`, since I'm loading very large photos inside a loop and that takes a lot of memory.

Comment: works fine for me, just checked your code with UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init], provide us your full code with image instance initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out. The problem was that I released a CGImageRef that I didn't own.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullResolutionImage];
```

If you get a `CGImageRef` by calling `fullResolutionImage`, you don't own it. Therefore, you don't need to release it yourself neither.

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Removing the last line fixed the problem for me.